# jQuery Mobile Styling not applied to elements added after DOM initialization?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using .insertAfter to stick some divs into my page after the DOM loads. Inside those divs are some `<a href="" data-role="button">Example</a>` elements, but they're not displaying as buttons. Just normal links. The jQuery Mobile CSS isn't being applied. Granted, this is all inside a giant data-role="none" div, but I have a data-role="listview" ul inside that same div and the JQM CSS is being applied to it perfectly well. Possibly because I used listview refresh on it? Is there some sort of equivalent method for other elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$('[type='submit']').button('refresh');

or

use

```
$('#urs_div').trigger('create');
```

Comment: So, the code would read as: $("<a id="return" href="" data-role="button">Example</a>").insertAfter('#top'); $('#return').trigger('create'); ?

Comment: What is your main div? If it's id 'return', You can use $('#return').trigger('create');

Comment: return is the id of the new anchor element being created. So I need to use the id of the parent div, and do it after inserting the new element?

Comment: yes. You can use parent div id for this. #('parentDIvID').trigger('create'); this is  in  last